# How to use UIWebView to get scrolling text?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview, uitextview

In my iPhone application I need a scrolling text.
I had the text to be displayed and scrolled up and down but I could not get customized text.
I mean all the text is of same font. I need some different font size text .
I am using UITextView, but UITextView do not support customized text in it.

How can I have the scrolling text which has different font size.
I read that to use UIWebView for this. But, I could not understand how to use it.
the text contains no url's no editing.(It need to be just static text to read).
How can I do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is a UI class which shows HTML pages. You will need to make an HTML page, optionally adorn it with some CSS, and load it into a UIWebView.

Comment: Thank you, @Costique. 
I used HTML code for the text to be of different font size and bold and font type.
Thank you.